# Filling a matrix with values

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, constants

I would like to hear your recommendations on when to use JavaScript's `const` over `let`, especially when applied to mutable objects as demonstrated in the following comparative code samples:

Strict preference of `let`:

```
// Create 100 x 100 zero-filled matrix:
let matrix = new Array(100);
for (let i = 0, length = matrix.length; i < length; ++i) {
  matrix[i] = new Array(100).fill(0);
}

// Fill matrix with values:
function fill(matrix, value) {
  for (let row of matrix) {
    row.fill(value);
  }
}
```

Strict preference of `const`:

```
// Create 100 x 100 zero-filled matrix:
const matrix = new Array(100),
      length = matrix.length;
for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  matrix[i] = new Array(100).fill(0);
}

// Fill matrix with values:
function fill(matrix, value) {
  for (const row of matrix) {
    row.fill(value);
  }
}
```

In my opinion, the `const` semantics in JavaScript are too weak to help static code analysis or to allow for compiler optimizations. Where `const` is (mis-)used to signal immutability, I'd go with e.g. declaring `ALL_CAPS` identifiers instead.

Is my thinking flawed? When writing robust, maintainable code, which of the above samples would you prefer? Is there a middle ground?

Comment: As it is currently framed, this question is asking about a best practice (let vs. const), with the code included merely as an example. The task (creating a matrix of zeroes and changing it to ones) doesn't look like it could be plausibly part of a real project. See [ask].

Comment: @200_success Above code samples are taken from a recent project that I own and maintain. Of course, I did not post the whole project but two relevant parts. Knowing this, would you mind re-opening my question?

Comment: Please show enough code to explain why you would want to change a matrix of zeroes to ones. Also retitle the question to state the task being performed rather than your main concern about the code.

Comment: @le_m: Regarding question from the title: programmers should always explicitly state their intentions, if you don't plan to have some variable change, declare it `const`. More about it in _"[how much should I be using 'let' vs 'const' in ES6?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653)"_. And what's regarding creating 2D array filled with some value in ES6, it's as simple and concise as `Array(x).fill().map(() => Array(y).fill(value))`.

Comment: @Przemek Thanks for your input! I actually read the linked question before posting here. Unfortunately, the answers given there are pretty ambiguous, e.g. "I recommend you use it all the places it makes sense." - yes, but where does it make sense? - Regarding your `Array(x).fill().map(() => ...)` - this is not very descriptive to me; you first create an empty array, fill it with `undefined`, then map arrays to the undefined values. IMHO a loop is more readable and more performant, but that isn't part of my review question anyways.

Comment: @200_success I changed the title to the task performed in these code samples I picked from my project and added a bit more code to make it clear that creating and filling are separate functions.

Comment: In my opinion, `const` should be used „by default” wherever possible, i.e. if variable doesn't need to be mutable. And what comes to that one-liner ― I personally find it way easier to read than the regular loop. In case of the latter, I would have to scan it all while here it's one, short chain of functions.

Comment: @Przemek So would you recommend `let matrix = Array(...)` since the matrix is mutable? And `const length = matrix.length` since its a non-mutable primitive? Regarding the functional syntax, having a one-liner is often easier to parse visually, right. Pretty subjective topic though...

Comment: I would go with `const` in both cases, your array itself doesn't change, it's values do.

Answer (score 2):

> In my opinion, the const semantics in JavaScript are too weak to help static code analysis or to allow for compiler optimizations. Where const is (mis-)used to signal immutability, I'd go with e.g. declaring ALL_CAPS identifiers instead.

All `const` does is assure you that the value assigned to it is the same value throughout the scope. If it was assigned an array, it will be the same array and not suddenly change to *another* array or a different value altogether.

Mutation of the value, however, is a different story. JavaScript has no concept of immutability.`Object.freeze` does exist, and primitives are immutable, but that's about it.

For your code, if you're aiming to avoid mutation of your arrays, temporary values, counters and all, swap your loop for `array.map` and create a range function. Create a range, map through it, fill it with values, repeat.

```js
function range(n){
  return Array(n).fill(0);
}

function matrix(dim, value){
  return range(dim).map(v => range(dim).map(v => value));
}

console.log(matrix(10, 2));
```

Comment: When performance is not a top priority, your immutable solution seems like a good choice to avoid the whole issue about const vs let. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: `return Array(dim).fill().map(() => Array(dim).fill(value))` does the same in [more efficient way](https://i.imgur.com/2MKwPmJ.png). It avoids one unnecessary `map()`.

Comment: @Przemek True. But I wasn't aiming for efficiency in particular, just getting rid of the variables. The OP can shorten it to that, I don't really mind.