# Class to create HTML heading tags in React

Tags: html, react.js, jsx

I have a class which is part of my page layout. It is creating header tag elements (`h1` - `h5`). Could someone tell me how I could improve it (I know it should be improved, but don't know how)? I have problem with rewriting almost the same code in switch cases. Would rather to create some kind of `<h{type}></h{type}>` code, but couldn't.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class TypographyHeader extends Component {
    createHeader() {
        let txt        = this.props.text;
        let spaceIndex = txt.indexOf(' ');
        let p2         = txt.substr(spaceIndex);

        txt =
            <span className="typography_header__distinctive_el">
                {txt.substr(0, spaceIndex)}
            </span>;

        switch(this.props.headerType) {
            case 1:
                return <h1 className="typography_header">{txt} {p2}</h1>;
            case 2:
                return <h2 className="typography_header">{txt} {p2}</h2>;
            case 3:
                return <h3 className="typography_header">{txt} {p2}</h3>;
            case 4:
                return <h4 className="typography_header">{txt} {p2}</h4>;
            case 5:
                return <h5 className="typography_header">{txt} {p2}</h5>;
        }

        return <h1 className="typography_header">{txt} {p2}</h1>;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.createHeader()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

TypographyHeader.propTypes = {
    headerType: PropTypes.oneOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Choosing the heading level at runtime:**

According to [the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime), you cannot use expressions within JSX types. However, you can use capitalized variables:

```
const Heading = "h" + 1;
return <Heading>...</Heading>;
```

**Further suggestions:**

- Rename `TypographyHeader` to `TypographyHeading` to avoid confusion with [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header).
- Rename `headerType` to [`level`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements).
- Rename `txt` to `text` in `let txt = this.props.text` for consistency's sake.
- Don't recycle the `txt` variable by rebinding it to a JSX `<span>`.
- Consider using `const` variable bindings.
- As there are 6 official heading levels, you might want to relax your `propTypes` constraints:

  ```
  headerType: PropTypes.oneOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).isRequired
  ```
- Use destructuring arguments to avoid writing `let txt = props.text`.
- Make the white space following the `<span>` element obvious by appending `{" "}`.
- Handle heading texts without spaces by splitting according to [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10272822/1647737).

**Proposed refactoring:**

```
function TypographyHeading({text, level}) {

    // Split text into leading and remaining words:
    const space = text.indexOf(" ");
    const leading = text.substr(0, space);
    const remaining = text.substr(space + 1);

    // Select heading <h1> - <h5>:
    const Heading = "h" + level;

    return (
        <div>
            <Heading className="typography_header">
                <span className="typography_header__distinctive_el">
                    {leading}
                </span>
                {" "}{remaining}
            </Heading>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's a very nice answer! Thanks! However, I've got a question. Why and when to use`const` instead of `let`? Is it in times, when variable does not change and for smaller memory usage?

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos Not rebinding ('recycling') a variable helps understanding and debugging of your code. Using `const` enforces that rule. Some enthusiasts recommend to use `const` wherever applicable. Which however can lead to a [strange (IMHO) mix of `let` and `const` depending on whether you deal with primitive types or objects](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161013/filling-a-matrix-with-values).